# Driver.getWindowHandles() is always returning 1 in IE11 on Windows 10, although there are two windows open

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

**Code in Context:**

```
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

        String firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
        handles.remove(firstWinHandle);

        String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();

        if (winHandle!=firstWinHandle){

            //To retrieve the handle of second window, extracting the handle which does not match to first window handle

            String secondWinHandle=winHandle; //Storing handle of second window handle

            //Switch control to new window

            driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);
        }
```

This code works perfectly on IE11 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 to switch to the second window, but doesn't work on Windows 10.

In case of Windows 10, `Java.util.NoSuchElement Exception` appears for line

`String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();`

*Selenium and IE version being used are 2.53.1.*

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Disabling the protected mode in the IE settings for all zones helped.